# Extract data from curl with a 2nd digit

Tags: arrays, json, curl

I would like to extract data from a json file. For now i want to take the value of that array but I can't really find a way to solve the problem with the second 0/1/2.

I have already tried this, but unfortunately it does not work

```
<?php echo $datasearch_stat[0]->statistics->0->value;?>
<?php echo $datasearch_stat[0]->statistics->[0]->value;?>
```

**My code:**

```
<?php
$url_stat = "....";

$curl_stat = curl_init($url_stat);
curl_setopt($curl_stat, CURLOPT_URL, $url_stat);
curl_setopt($curl_stat, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl_stat, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl_stat, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$stat = curl_exec($curl_stat);
curl_close($curl_stat);

$datasearch_stat = json_decode($stat);
?>

Value: <?php echo $datasearch_stat[0]->statistics->0->value;?>
```

Json file:

[image: json file example]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe add a print("<pre>"); print_r(datasearch_stat); print("</pre>");  I'm familiar with all of these, but I'm having trouble understanding what's going on here.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [statistics] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => dribbling
                            [translations] => stdClass Object
                                (

Comment: [name] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [EN] => Dribbles
                                        )
                                )
                            [value] => 12
                        )
  )
 )
)

Comment: As you clearly require php code, please add the php-tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> echo json_decode($stat,true)[0]["statistics"][0]["value"];

notice the "true" there, turns everything into arrays so you don't have to guess which parts are converted to objects and which are converted to arrays, they're all arrays with the 2nd true argument.